# Can I display a sortable list of products with their attributes per category?

Tags: grid-layout

Is it possible to show category products in a sortable list grid like this: http://www.mckenziesp.com/Black-Bear-McKenzie-C3453.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming than you know categories ids.

```
$categoryIds = array(2,4); //categories id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product',    'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
```

Now you have products by category id.

Display your grid:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Attribute 1</th>
    <th>Attribute 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php $foreach ($collection as $product): ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $product->getName() ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getAttribute1() ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getAttribute2() ?></td>
  </tr>
  ....
  ....
<?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The sortable grid view you need a plug-in or some javascript. Like this one:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/